# Drupal: Parent-child draggable table

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

So I've been going at this one for a while now. I'm trying to create a draggable table that has a parent-child relationship, but where the children cannot be moved out of the parent group, and all of the parents are sortable among each other. I've modeled my form and theme off of the admin menu code, and I have it duplicating that functionality. The problem is that I can move the children to another parent, or let it become a parent. As an illustration:

```
Category 1
|
|--Item 1
|--Item 2
Category 2
|
|--Item 3
|--Item 4
|--Item 5
```

I would like to be able to sort Item 1 and Item 2 with each other, and Item 3, Item 4, and Item 5 with each other, but not move them between Category 1 and Category 2. I also need to be able to sort Category 1 and Category 2 with one another, taking the children with them. I've went through so many combinations of `$action`, `$group`, `$subgroup` settings mixed with `$class` settings for the categories and items that I've lost track. Nothing I have tried so far has produced the desired result. Here's the relevant bits of my code as it is currently:

In my form:

```
$form['#tree'] = true;
foreach($categories as $cat) {
    if(!isset($form['categories'][$cat->cid])){
        $form['categories'][$cat->cid] = array(
            'weight' => array(
                '#type'         => 'weight',
                '#delta'        => 25,
                '#attributes'   => array('class' => array('item-weight', 'item-weight-' . $cat->cid)),
            ),
            'cid' => array(
                '#type'         => 'hidden',
                '#value'        => $cat->cid,
                '#attributes'   => array('class' => array('cid')),
            ),
        );
        foreach($cats[$cat->cid] as $item) {
            $form['categories'][$cat->cid]['items'][$item->id] = array(
                'weight' => array(
                    '#type'         => 'weight',
                    '#delta'        => 25,
                    '#default_value'=> $item->weight,
                    '#attributes'   => array('class' => array('item-weight', 'item-weight-' . $cat->cid)),
                ),
                'cid' => array(
                    '#type'         => 'hidden',
                    '#value'        => $cat->cid,
                    '#attributes'   => array('class' => array('cid')),
                ),
            );
        }
    }
}
```

In my theme:

```
$children = element_children($form['categories']);
$rows = array();
if(count($children) > 0) {
    foreach($children as $cid) {
        $row = array(
            drupal_render($form['categories'][$cid]['weight']) .
                drupal_render($form['categories'][$cid]['cid']),
        );

        $rows[] = array(
            'data' => $row,
            'class' => array('draggable', 'tabledrag-root'),
        );
        foreach(element_children($form['categories'][$cid]['items']) as $id) {
            $row = array(
                theme('indentation', array('size' => 1)) . drupal_render($form['categories'][$cid]['items'][$id]['name']),
                drupal_render($form['categories'][$cid]['items'][$id]['weight']) .
                    drupal_render($form['categories'][$cid]['items'][$id]['cid']),
            );

            $rows[] = array(
                'data' => $row,
                'class' => array('draggable', 'tabledrag-leaf'),
            );
        }
        drupal_add_tabledrag('cat-table', 'order', 'sibling', 'item-weight', 'item-weight-' . $cid);
    }
}


drupal_add_tabledrag('cat-table', 'match', 'parent', 'cid', 'cid', 'cid', true, 1);
$output = theme('table', array('header' => $headers, 'rows' => $rows, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'cat-table')));
$output .= drupal_render_children($form);
return $output;
```

I've read over the documentation for `drupal_add_tabledrag()`, looked at the code, looked at example code, and searched around drupal.org and Google, but haven't come up with anything.

My only solution so far is to copy and modify the tabledrag.js file to just eliminate those capabilities, but while stopping the indent problem with the items (meaning, not letting them be on the same as the categories), keeping them in the same category has been Not Fun.

I suppose the most important question is, using standard Drupal is this possible?

Comment: how abt using fieldset to format it ? http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#fieldset

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already done a lot of coding so you might not want to give it up at this point, but DraggableViews is great to accomplish this. You can set up a normal view and add this draggableviews filter, it adds a weight and optionally a parent reference. The view itself uses the same drag-n-drop system as the rest of Drupal's backend tables.

Alternatively you can use a term reference and tie taxonomy terms to nodes, and just use that drag-n-drop.

If I'm missing something in your needs, my apologies, just thought I'd offer this simpler solution as it has definitely served me well in the past. Best of luck either way.

Comment: How do you do this without a module? This should be possible with drupal_add_tabledrag, but I too cannot find a way to prevent cross parent dragging. The table I am sorting is a form, and not Views related whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Just finished adding this functionality to my module

https://github.com/player259/ajax_table

There is no help, demo is outdated, but I'm working on it from time to time

Sections support was achieved by overriding tabledrag.js functions

Use this snippet to insert table

```
$form['map'] = array(
  '#type' => 'ajax_table',
  '#header' => array(t('Element'), t('Settings'), t('Weight')),
  'rows' => array(),
  '#draggable' => array(
    // drupal_add_tabledrag will be called in theme layer
    // NULL first arg to apply to this table
    array(NULL, 'match', 'parent', 'perfect-form-parent', 'perfect-form-parent', 'perfect-form-index'),
    array(NULL, 'depth', 'group', 'perfect-form-depth', NULL, NULL, FALSE),
    array(NULL, 'order', 'sibling', 'perfect-form-weight'),
  ),
  '#draggable_groups' => array(),
);

foreach ($map as $i => $element) {

  // ... some logic

  $form['map']['rows'][$i] = array(
    'data' => array(
      'element' => array(),
      'settings' => array(),
      'tabledrag' => array(
        'index' => array(
          '#type' => 'hidden',
          '#value' => $element['data']['tabledrag']['index'],  
          '#attributes' => array('class' => array('perfect-form-index')),
        ),
        'parent' => array(
          '#type' => 'hidden',
          '#default_value' => $element['data']['tabledrag']['parent'],
          '#attributes' => array('class' => array('perfect-form-parent')),
        ),
        'depth' => array(
          '#type' => 'hidden',
          '#default_value' => $element['data']['tabledrag']['depth'],
          '#attributes' => array('class' => array('perfect-form-depth')),
        ),          
        'weight' => array(
          '#type' => 'weight',
          '#delta' => $max_weight,
          '#default_value' => $weight,
          '#attributes' => array('class' => array('perfect-form-weight')),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array($row_class_current, $row_class_child)),
  );

  // This means that row with $row_class_child class could have as parent
  // only row with $row_class_parent class
  // NULL means root - there are no parents

  $form['map']['#draggable_groups'][$row_class_child] =
    $depth ? $row_class_parent : NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem at work so posting here my solution since none i found worked correctly in all situation. It is done 100% in javascript, on the php side you just have to set tabledrag in match with parent on pid and sort with siblings on weight.

The current code work on the example module (tabledrag parent/child) to adapt it to your need, change the .example-item-pid by your class for the PID input field. You just need to add it to the example code to have it working and see if it corresponds to your need.

First function invalidate any attempt to drop elements that don't have the same parent (PID) than the target element.

Second Function bypass the dragRow function to drop the element in the correct place (= the last children of the target row) and at the right depth ( = same depth than the target row).

```
/**
 * Invalidate swap check if the row target is not of the same parent
 * So we can only sort elements under the same parent and not move them to another parent
 *
 * @override Drupal.tableDrag.row.isValidSwap
 */
// Keep the original implementation - we still need it.
Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.row.prototype._isValidSwap = Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.row.prototype.isValidSwap;
Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.row.prototype.isValidSwap = function(row) {
  if (this.indentEnabled) {
    if (row && $('.example-item-pid', this.element).val() !== $('.example-item-pid', row).val()) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Return the original result.
  return this._isValidSwap(row);
}

/**
 * Position the dragged element under the last children of the element target for swapping when moving down our dragged element.
 * Removed the indentation, since we can not change parent.
 * @override Drupal.tableDrag.row.dragRow
 */
Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.dragRow = function (event, self) {
  if (self.dragObject) {
    self.currentMouseCoords = self.mouseCoords(event);

    var y = self.currentMouseCoords.y - self.dragObject.initMouseOffset.y;
    var x = self.currentMouseCoords.x - self.dragObject.initMouseOffset.x;

    // Check for row swapping and vertical scrolling.
    if (y != self.oldY) {
      self.rowObject.direction = y > self.oldY ? 'down' : 'up';
      self.oldY = y; // Update the old value.

      // Check if the window should be scrolled (and how fast).
      var scrollAmount = self.checkScroll(self.currentMouseCoords.y);
      // Stop any current scrolling.
      clearInterval(self.scrollInterval);
      // Continue scrolling if the mouse has moved in the scroll direction.
      if (scrollAmount > 0 && self.rowObject.direction == 'down' || scrollAmount < 0 && self.rowObject.direction == 'up') {
        self.setScroll(scrollAmount);
      }

      // If we have a valid target, perform the swap and restripe the table.
      var currentRow = self.findDropTargetRow(x, y);
      if (currentRow) {
        if (self.rowObject.direction == 'down') {

          /**
           * When going down we want to position the element after the last children and not right under the currentRow
           */
          // create a new row prototype with currentRow
          var rowObject = new self.row(currentRow, 'mouse', self.indentEnabled, self.maxDepth, false);
          // extract all children
          var childrenRows = rowObject.findChildren();
          // if we have children
          if (childrenRows.length > 0) {
            // we change the row to swap with the last children
            currentRow = childrenRows[childrenRows.length - 1];
          } 

          self.rowObject.swap('after', currentRow, self);
        }
        else {
          self.rowObject.swap('before', currentRow, self);
        }
        self.restripeTable();
      }
    }
    /**
     * We have disabled the indentation changes since it is not possible to change parent.
     */

    return false;
  }
};
```